# Django: sending mails

Tags: django, email

I have a problem with the settings file
I try to configure the sending of mail but it not works

I wrote :

```
EMAIL_HOST= 'mailhost.onera'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'patrice.kerviel@onera.fr'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my-password'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

and i have the error:

STARTTLS extension not supported by the server

if i change :

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

I have the error :
AUTH extension not supported by the server

if I change :

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = None
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = None
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

Now, I have no error but no email is sent

what is this problem ?

Comment: You might want to change your password now, after making it available to the public. :-)

Comment: Yes, please now!!!! immediately!!!! change your password.

Comment: This seems similar to your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675093/django-throws-this-error-smtpexception-starttls-extension-not-supported-by-ser

Comment: In my case, its not working...

Answer (score 0):

I preferebly use [mandrilapp.com](https://mandrillapp.com), it is of almost free.Just signup and get API Key in settings.In order to integrate to django, use `djrill` .Simple steps

```
pip install djrill
```

In `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    "djrill"
)
```

In `settings.py`

```
MANDRILL_API_KEY = "****frtyy*******"
EMAIL_BACKEND = "djrill.mail.backends.djrill.DjrillBackend"
```

Then use `django.core.email` methods(send_mail, etc...).No formalities..Enjoy.. :)